# User session is lost on redirect back from payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, cybersource

I have configured Cybersource as my payment gateway, I am able to navigate to cybersource and make a payment and able to redirect back to the site successfully. Also i am able to Cancel the payment and redirect back to my website.

Im getting the response from the payment gateway.
But, user is getting logged out on redirecting back from the payment gateway.

1. I'm using https website.
2. Redirecting back to same URL (https).

Tho im able to re-login the user based on TransactionID. I want to make sure the user session is not lost and the user remain logged in.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well that's unfortunate, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Hi, im getting the response from payment gateway successfully. But the user session is lost and user is getting logged out from the system which shouldn't happen. How can i ensure user is still logged in?

Comment: & What exactly is the user logged into? You're own system or Cybersource? If its your own system, how are you storing the session? Are you destroying the session when the user leaves the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of your cookie same-site configuration.
You should use SameSite=None on your cookies attributes. Also if you use SameSite=None you should set the secure cookies attribute as well.

Comment: Hi .. thank you for this suggestion .. i have tried this and it works fine now. But is there any other solutions for this ?

Comment: Previously some other payment gateway was used for the project and for that we never faced this kind of issues.

Comment: This is because of some new rules from web foundation for improving security.

Comment: But shouldn't it have stopped old payment gateway also from working ?

Comment: @APB is it recommended to do so?