Facing session issues during Razorpay callback in CodeIgniter; redirects to login or payment page instead of success page after payment
When a parent completes the fee payment using Razorpay, the payment is processed successfully on the Razorpay side. However, after the payment, instead of redirecting the user to a success page, the application redirects the user back to the initial payment page. Additionally, the network logs indicate a 303 redirect to the login page, suggesting a session issue.
Observations:
Payment Flow:
The user initiates the payment from the payment details page.
After completing the payment, Razorpay shows a "Payment successful" message and indicates that it will redirect shortly.
Instead of being redirected to a success page, the user is taken back to the initial payment page or login page.
Network Logs:
The callback URL response includes a set-cookie header, indicating a new session is being created or the existing session is being reset.
The response status is 303, with a redirect to the login page.
Verified Session Configuration:
Ensured the session configuration in config.php is correctly set as follows:
Updated Callback Method with Logging:
Added detailed logging to the callback method in Razorpay.php to trace the session state and identify issues.
Updated callback method:
Testing:
After updating the configuration and callback method, the issue persists.
Logs indicate that the session might be resetting or not being maintained correctly during the callback.
Request for Help:
Could you please provide insights or suggestions on how to maintain the session correctly during the Razorpay callback? Any help to resolve the redirection issue and ensure the user is redirected to the appropriate success page after a successful payment would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Check the SameSite value your session ID cookie gets set with.

Yes, agreed with @CBroe . Add these configs in config.php $config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_samesite'] = 'None';
$config['cookie_secure']  = TRUE;

Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353521/user-session-is-lost-on-redirect-back-from-payment-gateway/66354648#66354648
